# hive table creation with udf

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, presto

I have chunk of data on s3 in orc format. my requirement is to mask certain columns. What will be the best approach with minimal change ?

Can I define hive table level udf and whenever the column is referred from hive/preso by default the udf will excute and mask the data on the fly ?

Your response will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is called column masking. 
To achieve this, you would typically use Presto (or Hive) with Ranger security, and configure column masking there.

Ranger defines a set of predefined masks (eg mask all but last 4 characters/digits, etc.).

Ranger also allows custom masks (free style expression), but that is not supported by Presto yet.

Comment: Currently we are on AWS, and security and roles are maintained using IAM. So Can I use Ranger to implement masking only ?